# Check if a function exists in specific file?

Tags: php

I would like to check if the `$this->_controller` function `foo` exist before I call it.

**Example of call:**

```
call_user_func_array([$this->_controller, $this->_url[1]]);
```

This will call the function `url[1]` in the controller inserted in the URL so, basically:

```
webserver/backend/foo
```

I want check if foo actually exists in the back-end.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are functions for most things. Check [`method_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php):

```
if(method_exists($this->_controller, $this->_url[1])) {
    call_user_func_array([$this->_controller, $this->_url[1]]);
}
```

For other uses see [`is_callable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php).